# WMI: Win32_PerfRawData_Counters_ProcessorInformation versus Win32_PerfRawData_PerfOS_Processor

Tags: wmi

Folks, I am looking to monitor stuff like "PercentProcessorTime", "Timestamp_Sys100NS" (Total Processor Time) using WMI.
The problem I am facing is, I find that Windows Server 2008 R2 have following two WMI Class:
Win32_PerfRawData_PerfOS_Processor
and 
Win32_PerfRawData_Counters_ProcessorInformation

Anyone know the difference between the two?

I should note, Win32_PerfRawData_Counters_ProcessorInformation isn't available in Windows Server 2003 or 2008, it is only available on 2008 R2.

I did some testing and it seems the two provide basically the same information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are exactly the same except that Win32_PerfRawData_Counters_ProcessorInformation provides more properties to measure.  PerfOS_Processor does not count the following as it's properties:

```
ParkingStatus
PercentofMaximumFrequency
PercentPriorityTime
ProcessorFrequency
ProcessorStateFlags
```